# Why do I have only one value stored in the collection if 2 or more values are checked?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have asked before about a problem regarding my binding with the checkbox.Finally a step forward! :) Now,I am wondering the following thing:I have a collection named SelectedCourses that stores all the courses checked in the checkbox. My problem is that when I check 2 or more courses,it only stores the first value from the list,even if I selected it after another value. My code for storing the values looks sth like this:

```
public void SaveTeacher(object param)
{
    using (DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand db = new DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand())
    {
        Cours c = new Cours();
        RegisterTeacher t = new RegisterTeacher();

        if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            foreach(var item in Courses)
            {
                if(item.IsChecked)//here IsChecked is true
                {
                    SelectedCourses = new ObservableCollection<Cours>();
                    SelectedCourses.Add(item);//here I have only one course  
                }
                SelectedCourses.ToList();
            }
        }
        t.SNTeacher = SNTeacher;
        t.UserName = _UserName;
        t.pwd = pwd;
        t.fullName = fullName;
        t.education = education;

        db.RegisterTeachers.Attach(t);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And my collection is this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Cours> selectedCourses;
public ObservableCollection<Cours> SelectedCourses
{
    get { return selectedCourses; }
    set
    {
        selectedCourses = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChange("SelectedCourses");
    }
}
```

I also have a collection that holds all the courses:

```
private ObservableCollection<Cours> _courses;
public  ObservableCollection<Cours> Courses
{
    get => _courses;
    set
    {
        _courses = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChange(nameof(Courses));
    }
}
```

This is how my system looks and an example of checking 2 values:

[image]

And this is what i get when I set the breakpoint:

[image]

As you can see,only one course is added to SelectedCourses.How can I make it so that it will save as many courses as the user checks?
And last but not least,the binding with the .xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="coursesList"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCourses}"  
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="538,23.2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225"  ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" Height="255" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxList" Content="{Binding Path=courseName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are creating a new `ObservableCollection` in each iteration.

Try it like this:

```
if (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
            SelectedCourses = new ObservableCollection<Cours>();

            foreach(var item in Courses)
            {
                if(item.IsChecked)//here IsChecked is true
                {
                    SelectedCourses.Add(item);//here I have only one course  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: However note that `SelectedCourses.ToList();` does nothing if you don't assign what's returned. (aside from consuming CPU)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nashmar but it doesn't work.It still takes only one value but now I have noticed something really bizzare:Even if I select for e.g only the course MIX,I still get SDJ3.I set the value of isChecked to true,otherwise it wouldn't work.Would this be the problem?

Comment: @oanad I'm no expert in WPF, but maybe the cause is in your bindings?

Comment: This is what i'm trying to do right now @Rafalon.I'm trying to do event handlers for the 2 states of the checkbox and see where this is going to take me.The rest of the binding is ok,I have this error for 2 weeks and nobody was able to help me with it until today.Now I will try to see if I'll manage to do this until the end.If not,then I'm gonna go with a different approach

Comment: Someone was solving a similar problem to yours. Have a look here [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/de4e5bde-0522-4fc9-8cd4-ec33d05f4037/get-selected-check-box-value-which-are-inside-list-box-using-mvvm?forum=silverlightmvvm)

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do the method and make a step forward!For those in need,this is the method which I use to get the checked values:

```
 public void CheckVal()
   {
 SelectedCourses = new ObservableCollection<Cours>();
                foreach (var item in Courses)
                {

                    if (item.IsChecked)
                    {
                        SelectedCourses.Add(item);

                    }
}
```

This is the binding with the View:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="coursesList" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="538,23.2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225"  ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" 
  Height="255" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBoxItem  IsSelected="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ElementName=CheckBoxList}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxList" Content="{Binding Path=courseName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And the rest is the same(the 2 collections and the IsChecked value) :).Hope it will be of some help for others.Thank you guys for your help!